# Southern Half of Corsica's GR20 hike in late October

Tags: hiking, trekking, weather, france

The [GR20](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GR_20) between Calenzana and Conca is considered one of Europe's best but also most difficult hikes. The recommended time of year to do this hike safely is usually given as June to mid-October.

Our travel plans would only allow us to be on Corsica in late October / early November.

As Wikipedia and other sources state, the southern part between Vizzavona and Conca is considered to be easier.

My question is:

- What types of difficulties are the reason why doing the hike later than mid-October is not recommended?
- Are they as relevant for the 'easier', lower altitude southern part?
- Would specific equipment and weather report information be more crucial than during summer?
- Is the northern part much more interesting and beautiful, such that you would recommend rather going for only that one or the full hike sometime in summer?

Comment: This question fits on both this site and our sister site the great outdoors, if you do not get answers here we can move it for you. Please do not post the same question on both sites.

Comment: It’s been 45 years so take with a grain of salt. I don’t recall the north being harder than the south, but we went south to north so we’re getting into shape on the south bit. We also were early in the season, with only one refuge open for business (others were unlocked but unattended). I’d say the worst thing will be snow coming in, so use a good forecast and good judgment.

Comment: Yes, the recommendations to go between June and mid-October are because of snow. However, because of the global warming during the past 30 years, the climbing season in Europe is now longer than in the past. IMO early November is still okay. Temperatures might be low and the mountains could be slightly dusted with snow, but that's about it. Oh yes, days are quite short in November, make sure you take that into account.

Comment: @JonCuster I suspect if it's about elevation rather than difficulty.  A quick check shows that the only summit over 2500m on the route is in the N half, where it also goes over 2000m 4 times.  in the S half it nearly reaches 2000m a couple of times, at the highest - so lower peak altitude, by enough to affect the chances of snow

Comment: @ChrisH-UK - seems reasonable. It’s been a long long time since I looked at the maps. Unlikely to get absolutely slammed by snow, but still a possibility.

Comment: @JonCuster I've only done the northern part, and that over 25 years ago, in summer.  So I had to have a look online, where I found elevation profiles.  There's also the issue of escape routes if the snow comes in on the high spots while you're in a valley with no easy way out

Comment: My girlfriend did this like 10 years ago very late in the season. Once the huts are closed, you will be carrying all your food and a tent for the whole trip

Comment: @Manziel my experience was the north section, in summer, but we were mainly camping, and carrying our food; resupply every 2-3 days was possible.  In that regard the southern half looks quite a lot more remote

Comment: I went in summer, north to south, and the biggest difference IMHO is terrain: in the north half, you basically cross a mountain ridge above the timber line every day, and everything is quite steep and stoney. The south part doesn't feel alpine anymore, for most parts. You still have more mountaineous crossings like Col de Pavella, but nothing really tough like theCirque de la Solitude. In worse weather, I'd find the south acceptable, probably not the north.